# How can I add "Work email" to Community Members list in SharePoint 2013 Community Site?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

The "Community Members" list in SharePoint 2013 Community Sites is a special list that only contains users who have clicked the "Join Community" button.  It is not the same list as the ACL "[SharePoint site] Members".

There is a list of the Community Members available in the /Lists/Members/MembersAllItems.aspx page, however that page does not show the members email address.

How can I get the "Work email" column added to this view similar to how it shows for the ACL "[SharePoint site] Members" view?

Community Members view:

[image: Community Members view]

ACL " Members" view:

[image: SharePoint site Members view]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the ribon and choose 'list'. From there choose 'list settings'. Click on the default view and edit it.  Add a column from existing fields. Choose 'work email'. Click ok.